How to access delta live table from one dlt pipeline to another dlt pipeline
I have one databricks streaming table which is updated by kafka as append mode and it running in continuous mode in dlt.
I have to use same kafka connection in another dlt so I though instead of creating new streaming table can I use already created streaming table.
But getting error

Dataset defined in the pipeline but could not be resolved.

I am reading already existed streaming table like below
df = spark.readStream("Streaming_table_Name")

What is the value you have put in the Streaming_table_Name ? You should NOT have LIVE as the schema since it was not defined in the same pipeline and you need the actual DLT schema which you specified while configuring the existing pipeline. Something like "<dlt_schema>.<Streaming_table_Name>
